# Chef Windows using attributes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How to use

In attributes\default.rb,

```
default['directory']['path'] = 'C:\test20777'
```

In receipes\default.rb,

```
directory #{node['directory']['path']} do   
  action :create  
end
```

Note: `*#{node['directory']['path']}*`  And `*node['directory']['path']*` (both are not working)

The above setup is not working. How to reference to attributes(some path such as c:\test20777) in receipe.

Answer (score 0):

So a few issues. First not strictly needed but as a good practice make that `C:\\test20777`. Second, it should just be `directory node['directory']['path'] do`. The `#{}` syntax only works inside double quoted strings, but you don't need it at all in this case since you just want the single value.